# How to create a simple Like Button?

Tags: html, web, button, widget

I need a simple like button. It must allow visitors to vote without logging into their social networks accounts.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure I understand... you want someone to like your page using facebook, but without being logged into facebook?

Comment: no, I want visitors to like my page or item on the page anonymously.

Comment: This one http://www.likebtn.com/en/ suited perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I recreated the Kudos buttom from [svbtle](https://svbtle.com/) as an intependent widget.

[kudosplease.com](http://kudosplease.com)

### What is a "Kudos"?

> To gain kudos is to earn respect and recognition. A one-element kudos widget with no dependencies.

["kudos" on urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kudos)

### How to use it

#### 1. Add the CSS/JS to your page

#### 2. Add the widget HTML

```
<div class="kudos" 
     data-amount="0" 
     data-url="domain.tld/my-awesome-article"></div>
```

#### 3. Initialize the widget via JS

```
new KudosPlease({ 
  el : '.kudos',
  duration : 1500,
  persistent : true,
  status : {
    alpha: 'fontelico-emo-shoot',
    beta: 'fontelico-emo-shoot',
    gamma: 'fontelico-emo-beer'
  }  
});
```

### Free API or host yourself

The amount of kudos for a specific url is saved in my backend, but you can also download it on GitHub: https://github.com/TimPietrusky/KudosPlease

### Examples

- [Kudos Please @CodePen](http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/acBCf)
- ["Tell us something about you" @CodePen](http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/Kazcy)

Answer (score 4):

I recreated a Medium-style applause button:

http://applause-button.com/

The button persists claps to a hosted back-end service, so no need to spin up your own database. Adding it is as simple as follows:

```
<head>
  <!-- add the button style & script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/applause-button.css" />
  <script src="dist/applause-button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- add the button! -->
  <applause-button style="width: 58px; height: 58px;"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store 'likes' in your own database.  Just have a 'like' link that hits the server and updates a count in the database table.  Of course this requires a database and server side language (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc).

The https://svbtle.com/ blog network has a cool little 'Kudos' button which anonymously likes when you hover over the kudos button.  http://howtomakelightning.com/365/

I am not sure how you would do it on a static website though.

Comment: Thank you.
Most of the pages of my website are cached, so website is "static".
Of course, I can make my own like button widget with PHP, but it would take time...
I tried to google some kind of free like button widget, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply create a like button :D
Your button will have store the "likes" somewhere (usually a database), which is by definition a dynamic process and find a way to deal with a few security and UX issues.

If you are using React I created this service https://lyket.dev/, that will take care of everything.